# How can I repair a tiny puncture in leather?

Tags: repair, furniture, upholstery

I rolled the back of my leather chair into the corner of a table and ended up with a tiny puncture maybe a millimetre or two across. Normally, damage like this wouldn't bother me but my chair is regularly walked past and I'm worried that something will snag in the leather and result in a larger tear.

See the damage below:
[image]

Does anyone have any tips for repairing tiny punctures like this? My priority is preventing further damage but preferably I'd like it to look as inconspicuous as possible.

All the advice that I have already seen online seems to involve inserting a patch into the tear and glueing the two edges down on to the patch. But this damage is too small for me to insert anything in to without making it larger first.

Comment: A small dab of white glue would seal it and dry clear. A touch of steel wool would take the shine off (but might look frosty). The cosmetics might not appeal, but it would reduce chance of snagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a toothpick to push a small square or circle of backer fabric through the hole to the back of the leather. Choose something thin but strong and that has a little give - silk is often used but not everyone has a tiny bit of silk in their sewing basket. This gives some support for step 2.
2. Use same toothpick to pick up a small dab of flexible, clear fabric glue through the hole to the backer fabric behind.
3. The use a spoon to push the leather onto the fabric backer and rub it down to ensure the glue is well and good squished behind and around the hole, and that there are no edges to the tear that might catch again. If you can push the leather together you can make the hole practically invisible. No glue should be visible from the outside except the tiniest amount inside the seam itself.

Answer (score 2):

I poked a hole in the leather seat of my truck. I picked up a patch kit at the auto parts store mixed the colors untill I got a good match. I put the stuff on and used the texture pad on top and it looked really good even after a year of my big but climbing in. I did not put anything behind the hole as it was a puncture a bit larger than yours I think the kit cost under 20$.